# CAAnimationGroup Running Too Fast

Tags: ios, xcode, cabasicanimation, caanimation

My CAAnimationGroup is running too fast.  I want it to take a total of 50 seconds to do something, and it is doing it in about 3...it breezes through the first animation, and does the other one slow.

```
hover = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
        hover.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
        hover.removedOnCompletion = NO;
        hover.additive = YES; // fromValue and toValue will be relative instead of absolute values
        hover.fromValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointZero];
        hover.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(26*22, 26*-10.0)]; // y increases downwards on iOS
        hover.autoreverses = FALSE; // Animate back to normal afterwards

        hover.repeatCount = 0; // The number of times the animation should repeat

       CABasicAnimation *fall = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
        fall.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
        fall.removedOnCompletion = NO;
        fall.additive = YES; // fromValue and toValue will be relative instead of absolute values
        fall.fromValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(26*22, 26*-10.0)];
        fall.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(26*22, guess1*700.0)]; // y increases downwards on iOS
        fall.autoreverses = FALSE; // Animate back to normal afterwards

        fall.repeatCount = 0; // The number of times the animation should repeat

        CAAnimationGroup*   group = [CAAnimationGroup new];
        group.beginTime = 0.;
        [group setDuration:50.0];
        group.animations = @[ hover, fall ];

        [theDude.layer addAnimation:group forKey:@"myHoverAnimation"];
```

Comment: Why do you animate the same property with two animations? I think that can't work.

Comment: @macmoonshine I want it to complete the first animation, and then run the second animation.

Comment: You should use `CAKeyframeAnimation` (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/cakeyframeanimation) instead.

Answer (score -1):

Judging by your implementation, I'm assuming you want a `sequence` of animations on an object `theDude` on it's `position` property.

You can achieve the animation by using `CATransaction` using it's completion blocks. More can be read [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/catransaction).

Comment: `CATransaction` is not for sequencing animations together. If you apply several transactions in the same run of the runloop, the animations all run in parallel.